# The key exist in the map variable but find cannot find it

Tags: c++

I have created a class named as `MyClass` and define the map as:

```
    map<string,myClass> myClassSample;
```

I inserted a variable and key:

```
     myClassSample["id"].setString1_1("hi");
```

Note: `setString1_1` is the setter of the class

Then I use this code to see if the key is available:

```
    if (myClassSample.find("id") != myClassSample.end())
    {
    printf("Problem");
    }
```

`Problem` shown as out put. So the condition is TRUE!
but the function can return the string!

```
return myClassSample["id"].getString1();
```

Note: `getString1` is the getter of the class

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If it's giving output, that means `find` found it, which contradicts your title.

Comment: You'll most likely need to show us what `myClass` looks like, especially the `setString` and `getString` methods.

Comment: If I use `myClassSample["id"].getString1()` I will get the the string but the myClassSample.find("id") != myClassSample.end()1 is TRUE

Comment: `(myClassSample.find("id") != myClassSample.end()) == true` because you added the key `id` to the map. What's the problem?

Comment: `myClassSample.find("id") != myClassSample.end()` this means it cannot find the"id"!

Comment: `...find(...)` returns the place where your element can be found. `...end()` is a special place that means "not there". `...find(...)== ...end()` means the key is not found. `...find(...)!= ...end()` means the key is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how [`map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) works. It returns the `end()` iterator when the key you're searching for **cannot be found**. So your condition to check if the key is present needs to be

```
if (myClassSample.find("id") == myClassSample.end())
//                           ^^   ==, not !=
{
  printf("Problem");
}
```